# Convert object value from string to normal value (it's original data type)

Tags: javascript, json, object

So I have an object like this:

```js
let obj =  {
    first: "{\n  name: \"Todo name\",\n  location: \"New York NY USA\",\n  due: \"9am\",\n  figureType: \"icon\",\n  icon: \"fa-school\",\n  img: null,\n  emoji: null\n}",
    second: "{\n  name: \"Todo name2\",\n  location: \"New York NY USA\",\n  due: \"9am\",\n  figureType: \"icon\",\n  icon: \"fa-school\",\n  img: null,\n  emoji: null\n}"
}
```

The problem is the `object` inside the `first` is a string but not the whole object (`obj`) so I can't use `JSON.parse` to get it back to being a normal object.

Now the question is how can I make only the `value` back to normal object?

Comment: Have you posted the correct object? It would give a syntax error with the placement of your quotes

Comment: `↵` looks like a line feed. please add the code from the editor, not from the console.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Please read the question again as I added the code

Comment: @NinaScholz ...

Comment: The reason why it's like that is that I copied the object from the localStorage so it put these line breaks in it automatically

Comment: You can try `obj.first = JSON.parse(obj.first);` but `obj.first` isn't a valid JSON string.

Comment: `let obj =  {
        first: '{\n name: "Todo name",\n location: "New York NY USA",\n due: "9am",\n figureType: "icon",\n icon: "fa-school",\n img: null,\n emoji: null}'
        ,    
        second:'{\n  name: \"Todo name2\",\n  location: \"New York NY USA\",\n  due: \"9am\",\n  figureType: \"icon\",\n  icon: \"fa-school\",\n  img: null,\n  emoji: null\n}'
    }`
If you need a string value inside of the "obj" then you need to cover all string by quotes.
Second problem is the lost comma! You need to add a comma between first and scond object in the obj.

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi show us how you get and save  it to local storage

Answer (score 1):

If `obj.first` is a valid JSON string, you can convert it back to object like this:

```
    obj.first = JSON.parse(obj.first);
```

The same applies to `obj.second`.

Comment: The problem is:- It says that the object is already not a string so I can't parse it twice

Comment: How did the object end up like that? Did you receive it from somewhere else, or you created the object yourself?

Comment: I created it myself but the problem is I'm retrieving it from localStorage that's why it's like that.

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi I still don't understand how it ended up like that. Can you update the question to show how you saved it to localStorage?

Comment: I'll try to use different approaches to the problem. Thanks anyway. And if I succeeded I'm going to add the answer here for others to benefit from this. 
Thanks a lot again